# Equivalent of Haskell's const function in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Does Ramda have a function that works the same as [Haskell's `const` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const), i.e. takes two parameters and returns the first one?

I'm aware that it could be easily implemented as `R.curry((a, b) => a)`, but if Ramda already has such a function, I think I should use it instead of my own implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramda doesn't provide a function of type `a -> b -> a`. As Gothdo's answer states, Ramda does provide [`R.always :: a -> (() -> a)`](http://ramdajs.com/0.23.0/docs/#always) which is similar.

Adding an `a -> b -> a` function to Ramda was proposed in [ramda/ramda#1680](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1680), but that thread has not been active for some time.

Sanctuary does provide a true `const` function, [`S.K :: a -> b -> a`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#K).

Answer (score 1):

This function is named [`always`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#always) in Ramda.

> Returns a function that always returns the given value. Note that for non-primitives the value returned is a reference to the original value.
>
> This function is known as `const`, `constant`, or `K` (for K combinator) in other languages and libraries.